# I don't understand the one-to-one relationship in mongoDB Prisma

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, prisma

Suppose,
In mongoDB prisma model if I have two models A and B

```
model A {
  id                     String        @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  b                      B             @relation(fields: [bId], references: [id])
  bId                    String        @unique @db.ObjectId
}
```

```
model B {
  id                     String        @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  a                      A             @relation(fields: [aId], references: [id])
  aId                    String        @unique @db.ObjectId
}
```

I want model A have `bId` and also in model B have a `Id`

But I am getting error:

```
Error parsing attribute "@relation": The relation field `maleShops` on Model `Shop` must not specify the `fields` or `references` argument in the @relation attribute. You must only specify it on the opposite field `shop` on model `MaleShops`.
```

Answer (score 0):

One side should store the foreign key in a 1-1 relation, because if you need bId when create model A and need aId when create model B this make deadlock because both models need id of each other when create them, so you need to remove one of ids, or The relationship must be optional in that case. for more info [here](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-schema/relations/one-to-one-relations#choosing-which-side-should-store-the-foreign-key-in-a-1-1-relation)